# Animate App Bar Icon

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I make my geolocalisation App Bar Icon animate (rolling) when a user taps it ? Since geolocalisation takes time, and I don't want to put a progress bar...

Comment: Why don't you want to use a progress bar? It's a defacto standard. Would users spot animation in the app bar?

Comment: @Matt : I'm in a pivot view. If the user taps the geolocate icon, he might not expect a progress bar somewhere up the view. I thought animating the button would make more sense...

Comment: Same here. You can't animate a WP7 AppBarIcon so a PerformanceProgressBar is the best available option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the bar doesn't support regular SL animation items like storyboard, you could try swapping the image the button uses on a timer, but for me, the answer was to simply disable the button while the GPS was searching, or if the user hit it again, ignore it.

Or put up the progress bar, the user will get the idea quickly.